# Did I do the boss fight right? Or did I mess up?

Tags: undertale

After I beat Omega Flowey, and spared him, and it sent me back to the beginning of the Asgore fight, which is what's supposed to happen. I looked up a video online, and it said that Undyne calls you, once you get to the core. I forgot how to get to the "Core" so I got a bit off track. When I finally got to the core, I was not called, and when I tried to call Papayrus, he picked up, then said "you don't have to say goodbye." and hung up.
Is this supposed to happen? Should I still go to Snowdin Town?
If this helps, I was running neutral.

Answer (score 2):

If your phone option is only Papyrus, it sounds like you haven't befriended Undyne.

To do so you need 0 EXP and must have given her water when she collapsed in Hotland. If you did both of those, go to her house in Waterfall.

After this you will instead have Papyrus & Undyne in your phone menu. You should get the call after entering and leaving the core.

Comment: Slight correction: If you already meet the other requirements, then Undyne will give you the letter immediately after befriending her in Waterfall, and will not require you to backtrack to the CORE. This usually only happens if you failed to befriend her on the first run.